# Wiring vs Arduino

Tags: arduino, wiring

What are the key differences between Wiring and Arduino?

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wiring was an older attempt at what the Arduino has succeeded in doing. It was designed to be an educational platform for learning about microprocessors, software, and physical computing.

The Wiring board has a different processor and more robust hardware then the Aduino Duemilanove. It has more I/O pins, more memory, more interrupts, etc (although fewer then an Arduino Mega). It is also quite a bit more expensive.

The language is essentially the same, and each has an IDE based on the one written for processing.

Here is a page comparing the Wiring board to (older) arduinos and other platforms.

http://wiring.org.co/hardware/compare.html